# With respect to the all columns, how to sort the entire data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to sort a data frame having more than one column. Sorting has to be done with respect to all columns in the data frame. I have some random data frame named `dd`, given below:

```
  a          b       c         d
SDSGFD   DFJWEFH    DHWKEF   JHVFKSJD
SDSGFD   DFJWEFH    DHWKEF   1JHVFKSJD
SDSGFD   DFJWEFH    ADHWKEF  JHVFKSJD
4SDSGFD  DFJWEFH    DHWKEF   JHVFKSJD
SDSGFD   BDFJWEFH   DHWKEF   JHVFKSJD
SDSGFD   B1DFJWEFH  DHWKEF   JHVFKSJD`
```

I sorted that data frame by passing the column names into the `arrange()` method, given below:

`arrange(dd, a)` it will sort according to the column 'a'.

`arrange(dd, a,b)` and `arrange(dd, a,b,c,d)` like I have passed all column to sort the data frame and it does the sort as per requirement.

But let's assume, we don't know the number of columns and their names. I tried it by passing `names()` to the `arrange()` function;

`arrange(dd,names(dd))` but it gave an error:

> Error: incorrect size (4) at position 1, expecting : 6

Please suggest me how to sort the data frame in this scenario when we have to pass all the columns but we don't have any prior knowledge about the number of columns and their names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `arrange_all` which would arrange by all the columns without specifying the names

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange_all()

#        a         b       c         d
#1 4SDSGFD   DFJWEFH  DHWKEF  JHVFKSJD
#2  SDSGFD B1DFJWEFH  DHWKEF  JHVFKSJD
#3  SDSGFD  BDFJWEFH  DHWKEF  JHVFKSJD
#4  SDSGFD   DFJWEFH ADHWKEF  JHVFKSJD
#5  SDSGFD   DFJWEFH  DHWKEF 1JHVFKSJD
#6  SDSGFD   DFJWEFH  DHWKEF  JHVFKSJD
```

It gives the same order when we use individual columns in `arrange` for this example

```
identical(df %>% arrange(a, b, c, d), df %>% arrange_all())
#[1] TRUE
```

Which in base R can be done using `order` and `do.call` (thanks to @thelatemail)

```
df[do.call(order, df), ]
```

Comment: Or `df[do.call(order, df),]` outside of *dplyr* world.

Comment: This is what I missed, thank you all for helping me.